# How to insert new line in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to make new line when the column length > 100 in PostgreSQL query, here is my code:

```
SELECT message,  CASE WHEN length(message) > 100 
THEN  message||'\n' end as res FROM msg.list_trx
```

but my query doesn't work.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: This is crazy! it works on a varchar field but not on a text field, but you can still prepend to it eg '\n'||message works!

Comment: Crazier still works on 9.3.9 for both text and varchar I guess you will have to file a bug report with reproducible data

Comment: sorry, it's work but not like my expectation

Answer (score 10):

You are missing `e` right before new line literal (it is required for c-like special chars):

```
SELECT message,  CASE WHEN length(message) > 100 
THEN  message||e'\n' end as res FROM msg.list_trx
```

Have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html at paragraph

> 4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-Style Escapes

for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regexp_replace()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). The query below splits long messages into lines of 30 characters:

```
create table messages (id int, message text);
insert into messages values 
(1, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt'),
(2, 'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque');

select id, regexp_replace(message, '(.{30})', e'\\1\n', 'g')
from messages

 id |         regexp_replace         
----+--------------------------------
  1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co+
    | nsectetur adipiscing elit, sed+
    |  do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  2 | Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis+
    |  iste natus error sit voluptat+
    | em accusantium doloremque
(2 rows)
```

Comment: i've try not be two line bro just spliting

Comment: i've tried in this example http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html
but the example spliting to be  some of part and some row, i want to spliting to be new line but still in one row.

Comment: Look at my example. The values in the second column are multiline but there are still 2 rows. This values are just strings with new line character inserted every 30 position.

Comment: sorry but when i am trying it's not inserted new line,but every 30+ caharacter is gone

Comment: Well, you probably made a mistake. Unfortunately, I cannot see your tests. Maybe ask a new question with your last try?